# one kibana connect to multiple elastic clusters

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elasticsearch-7, kibana-7

I have the latest 7.10 elastic and Kibana on Kubernetes, I couldn't understand from docs if there's an option to connect multiple elastic clusters to one Kibana (as in Grafana)? If yes can you please share documentation? I only see cross cluster which replicate elastic clusters. I appreciate any help.

https://elasticsearch:443/elastic/_cluster/settings

```
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster_one": {
          "seeds": [
            "127.0.0.1:9200"
          ],
          "transport.ping_schedule": "30s"
        },
        "cluster_two": {
          "mode": "sniff",
          "seeds": [
            "192.88.88.88:443"
          ],
          "transport.compress": true
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [cross cluster search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/modules-cross-cluster-search.html#modules-cross-cluster-search). It allows you to run search request against two or more clusters. Please be aware of that
Cross-cluster search requires [remote clusters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/modules-remote-clusters.html).

> Once your Elasticsearch clusters are configured for cross-cluster
> search, you can create specific index patterns in Kibana to search
> across the clusters of your choosing. Using the same syntax that you’d
> use in a raw cross-cluster search request in Elasticsearch, create
> your index pattern in Kibana with the convention
> :

Remember that cross cluster search can search remote clusters that are one major version ahead or behind the coordinating node’s version.

Comment: thanks, lets assume that I site 1 with elastic and kibana  and site 2  with elastic. I configured remote cluster in my site 1 elastic, and they both has the same index test , can I now connect to site 1 kibana and see in test the documents of both elastics?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean exactly. If you have some specific issue while setting this up I highly encourage you to place a new question with your config details, attempts, error. Having enough insight is helpful to provide some tips.

Comment: basically that's what I try to understand in first place , once I configured remote cluster I can see both elastic data in Kibana?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that as explained in the docs.

Comment: when I query remote cluster like : cluster_two/index_name it works,but im not able to see this index in cluster 1 kibana, do I need to configure anything additional to that?